# Avoid magic number when looking for min value

Tags: c#, linq

I need to find min in a list of dictionaries by key. Here's how I do it:

```
public int GetMin(string key, List<Dictionary<string,int>> db)
        {
            if (db==null || db.Count==0)
            {
                return 0;
            }

            int result = Int32.MaxValue;

            foreach (var dic in db)
            {
                if (dic.TryGetValue(key,out int value) && result>value)
                {
                    result = value;
                }
            }
            return result == Int32.MaxValue ? 0 : result;
        }
```

It's not ideal, because it uses Int32.MaxValue as a baseline.

Here's a test list of dictionaries that I'm using.

```
var db = new List<Dictionary<string, int>>()
            {
                new Dictionary<string, int>(){ {"a", 1 }, { "b", 5 }, { "c", 3 } },
                new Dictionary<string, int>(){ {"d", 5 }, { "b", 3 } },
                new Dictionary<string, int>(){ {"a", 2 }, { "c", 2 } },
            };
```

Expected output:

```
"a" then result is 1, if "b" then 3, if "e" then 0, if "c" then 2
```

Is there anyway to do this better and more efficiently?

I also tried to do this with Linq but it looks a little ugly. Maybe easier ways to do this with linq?

```
  var result =  db.SelectMany(d => d)?.Where(kvp=>kvp.Key==key)?.OrderBy(x=>x.Value).FirstOrDefault().Value;
            return result ?? 0;
```

Comment: Idk if I'd consider that using a magic value. It has a clear name and it's purpose should be fairly obvious from context.

Comment: what is expected output.

Comment: @Carcigenicate, what if the dictionary contains Int32.MaxValue?

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar, in my example above if we pass "a" then result is 1, if "b" then 3, if "e" then 0, if "c" then 2

Comment: @user194076 When I've had similar problems, if the data potentially contained the highest possible value for that type, I decided I should probably be using a type with a larger max; otherwise, I'm risking overflows or errors (depending on the behavior of the language).

Comment: The linq post is the simplest.  Much easier if you have Dictionary<string, List<int>>

Comment: @jdweng, can you elaborate? I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: Have one dictionary and make the integers a list object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A way to avoid using `Int32.MaxValue` as baseline and to avoid returning `0` when no result has been found, is to work with `Nullable<int>`, or with the shorthand `int?`.

```
public static int? GetMin(string key, List<Dictionary<string, int>> db)
{
    int? result = null;
    if (db != null) {
        foreach (var dic in db) {
            if (dic.TryGetValue(key, out int value) && (result == null || value < result)) {
                result = value;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

If `null` is returned, it means that no match was found. If you prefer to use `int` as return type and to return `0` in this case, write.

```
return result ?? 0;
```

The usage of nullable ints inside the method is still useful, as it allows us to avoid abusing `Int32.MaxValue`. Now `Int32.MaxValue` can be a valid input and result.

There is nothing wrong with loops. Not everything needs to be LINQ. If you want to use LINQ, make sure to use the `Min` overload working with nullables. The non-nullable variant throws an exception for empty inputs. LINQ variants enumerating the dictionary (with `SelectMany`) are not using the advantage of fast dictionary lookups and are not efficient.

```
public static int? GetMinLINQ(string key, List<Dictionary<string, int>> db)
{
    if (db == null) {
        return null;
    }
    return db
        .Select(d => (isMatch: d.TryGetValue(key, out int i), result:i))
        .Where(x => x.isMatch)
        .Select(x => (int?)x.result)
        .Min();
}
```

It combines the return value of `TryGetValue` and the `out` variable into a value tuple. But the resulting method is not shorter than the one using a loop.

Comment: Creating nullable int `result` in function and using null coalescing operator while returning result is redundant I believe.. If I am wrong then kindly elaborate why you used `int? result`. Directly you can use `result = 0` and return it as result as I did in my answer

Comment: It depends whether you want to be able to differentiate between the result "no match was found" (=`null`) and "this min value was found". Then using `int?` as result type is appropriate. If you want to return `0` instead, a `int?` is still useful inside the method to avoid using `Int32.MinValue`. Of course you could also use a separate `bool` flag instead.

Comment: This is the right approach for me. Many people are missing the fact that nullable overloads of `Min`, `Max` and `Average` return `null` for empty sets rather than throwing. They work pretty well with query providers like EF, Hh etc. because that's natural for corresponding SQL functions. +1. Just want to suggest for the LINQ implementation the following equivalent "one-liner":  `return db?.Min(dic => dic.TryGetValue(key, out var value) ? (int?)value : null);` (don't want to post it as my own separate answer because the essential part is the usage of `int?` from this answer)

Comment: Thanks, I like the idea of using int? for comparisons instead of Int32.MaxValue more

Comment: @IvanStoev: I was not sure how `Min` treats `null` input values. A test shows that nulls are discarded, so your solution does work. `(new int?[] { 0, 1, null }).Min()` ==> `0`.

Answer (score 0):

You can write one function, where you can check if `key` is available in dictionary or not.

If dictionary contains key, then return `Min` from it, if not exist then just return 0

Implementation:

```
   public static int GetMinFromDictionaryList(List<Dictionary<string, int>> parameter, string key)
    {
        var keyValuePairList = parameter.SelectMany(d => d).Select(x => x.Key);
        if (keyValuePairList.Contains(key))
        {
            return parameter.SelectMany(d => d).Where(x => x.Key == key).ToList().Min(x => x.Value);
        }
     return 0;
    }
```

POC : [.NetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Iw7GRi)

Comment: This will throw an exception if there's no value in the dictionary with a given key.

Comment: @user194076, Now it supports condition which you mentioned in above comment

Answer (score 0):

I dont see what the problem is, this should be very simple.

Se the example below.

```
public static void Main()
{
   var db = new List<Dictionary<string, int>>()
        {
            new Dictionary<string, int>(){ {"a", 1 }, { "b", 5 }, { "c", 3 } },
            new Dictionary<string, int>(){ {"d", 5 }, { "b", 3 } },
            new Dictionary<string, int>(){ {"a", 2 }, { "c", 2 } },
        };
    // Result you will get is 1
    Console.Write(GetMin(db, "a").ToString());

}

public static int GetMin(List<Dictionary<string, int>> db, string key)
{
        return db == null || !db.Any(x=> x.ContainsKey(key)) ? 0 :
        db.SelectMany(x=> x).Where(x=> x.Key == key).Select(x=> x.Value).Min();

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but I can't change the signature of the method. (i.e. I have to use List<Dictionary<string,int>>)

Comment: Well if you have to use a list of Dictionary it should still be simple. i have updated my answer, se the code above.

Comment: `.SelectMany(x => x)` is not efficient. Your implementation is O(n²) while [the optimal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56201381/11178549) is O(n).

Comment: Oh Ok how would you have done it? and also if we are talking about smal amount of object then this is not really a problem. if there is more then 200 objects then we would need to optimize it and there is a 1000 way of doing it :)

Answer (score 0):

Since the only problem in the LINQ's query is to evaluate the minimum value when the collection is empty (no matching key is found, so an exception is raised), prepending [DefaultIfEmpty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.defaultifempty) to **`Min()`** allows to simply return `0`when the **`Where()`** filter is not returning any element.

The use of nullables or pre-filtering are not required:

```
public int GetMin(string key, List<Dictionary<string, int>> db)
{
    if (db is null) return 0;
    return  db.SelectMany(d => d).Where(kvp => kvp.Key == key).DefaultIfEmpty().Min(v => v.Value);
}
```

Comment: This is a very clean Linq. Much cleaner than mine. And I think DefaultIfEmpty() usage is clever. Thanks for this!

Answer (score 0):

You can write this as one sequence of LINQ methods.

So you have a string `key` and a sequence of similar dictionaries, each dictionary is a `Dictionary<string, int>`. And you want the lowest integer value where the dictionary key equals 'key'. If none-of the items contains `Key`, you want to return zero.

Well luckily, `Dictionary<string, int>` implements `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, int>>`, so you can use `SelectMany`, `Where`, `Select` and `Aggregate`

```
string key = ...
List<Dictionary<string, int>> myListOfDictionaries = ...
// note: this implements IEnumerable<IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, int>>>
// so a sequence of sequences of KeyValuePairs

var smallestIntThatHasKey = myListOfDictionaries

    // make one list containing all keyValuePairs
    .SelectMany(dictionary => dictionary)
    // result: one sequence of KeyValuePairs

    // keep only those KeyValuePairs where the Key equals key
    .Where(keyValuePair => keyValuePair.Key == key)
```

From the resulting sequence I want the one with the smallest Value. I could order all values in descending order and take the first one:

```
.Select(keyValuePair => keyValuePair.Value)
.OrderBy(value => value)
.FirstOrDefault();
```

This will properly return zero if there is no item with key. It is also not a very smart solution: if you found the first element in your sort order (which is the smallest), why bother to sort the 2nd, the 3rd etc, if you are only going to use the first one. Better use `Aggregate`:

```
.Select(keyValuePair => keyValuePair.Value)
.Aggregate(0,(minValue, enumeratedValue) =>
    (enumeratedValue < minValue) ? enumeratedValue : minValue);
```

This will seed your aggregated result with zero. It will pass your sequence only one: it will check the minValue with the enumerated value and keep the smallest one as aggregated value